# GridView and items control isSelected bound to same property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

Im seeing odd behavior when having my `DataGrids selectedItem` and and my `ListBox SelectedItem` both bound to the same property.

my backing collection is a `DataTable`. I have a `DataGrid` with the `ItemSource` bound to the `DataTable`. I also have an `ListView` with its `ItemSource` bound to the same `DataTable`. One view is a grid display of the data, and the other is basically a time line showing the same data visually. Im drawing the items on a canvas which is the `ItemsTemplate` for the `ListViewItems`. I then have a `SelectedItem` property in my view model that is bound to both collections `SelectedItem`. All this is working fine, i select one in the `ListBox` it gets selected in the `DataGrid` and vise versa. I then  have a `popup` on each `ListViewItem` whose `isOpen` property is bound to the `isSelected` property of the `ListboxItem` so if you click on an item in the `listbox` the popup shows you some info on the item.

The problem is, when  i click an item in the `DataGrid` I can see the corresponding item in the `ListView` is being selected however the popup is not appearing. The weird thing is that if i arrow up or down in the `DataGrid` the popups do appear, or if i click and drag my mouse selecting rows up and down in the `DataGrid` the popups also appear. However, if i click a single row in the `DataGrid` the popup does not appear, even though I can see visually the item in the `ListBox` did get selected. I think clicking the cell is somehow eating the selected item or something but im not sure. Kinda stumped on this one. Hopefully my description makes sense.

ListView:(view)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultsView}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Transparent" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent" Width="Auto"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Rectangle Width="5" Height="9" />
                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" StaysOpen="False">
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

DataGrid:(view)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultsView}" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="true" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True"
        SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

ViewModel Properties:

```
#region ResultsView
private DataView _ResultsView = new DataView();
public DataView ResultsView
{
    get
    {
        return _ResultsView;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_ResultsView != value)
        {
            _ResultsView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ResultsView");
        }
    }
}
#endregion  

#region SelectedEvent
    private DataRowView _SelectedEvent;
    public DataRowView SelectedEvent
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedEvent;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedEvent != value)
            {
                _SelectedEvent = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedEvent");
            }
        }
    }
#endregion
```

Comment: A simple cut-down version of the code that demonstrates your problem would go a long way to allowing people to help.

Comment: Added code, hopefully it will help.

Comment: Could be related to StaysOpen=false. StaysOpen=false means the Popup will close when the Popup loses focus. Considering that the Popup never has focus in your scenario (because you're working with the DataGrid at the time) it may be that it's behaving correctly (Popup not showing as the DataGrid has focus, not the Popup). I'm surprised you see the Popup when you do the up/down interaction as according to StaysOpen, it should not be displayed.

Comment: Well done, removing the StaysOpen=False has it behaving as expected. I knew it was something silly I was overlooking. I too was confused as why it was working when arrowing or dragging the mouse.